# CSS for Mobie site - search box and button combined 100% width?

Tags: css, mobile-safari

Im trying to optimise my site for mobile. Im going with a 1 column liquid layout. The issue im having is that I cant get my search box and submit button to be 100% wide.

This is that I want:

[image: Width]

I cant set a fixed width for the search box (an input). It also seems to ignore width: 100% and absolute positioning. Is there anyway of achieving this? I thought maybe if I made the input an inline element it would flow to 100%, but it doesn't seem to. Thanks

UPDATE - What about this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdln/3ms5f/

Ive made the search box 100% wide, but put it in a container div which has 5em of padding on the right. As the container div is 100% wide its knocks the button to the new row, but ive 'lifted' the button with absolute positioning.

It seems to work well when I resize the window. I thought the layout would be more robust if I used em for the widths instead of px, which means Ive had to normalize the text sizes.

Are there any issues with my solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jdln/3ms5f/

Ive made the search box 100% wide, but put it in a container div which has 5em of padding on the right. As the container div is 100% wide its knocks the button to the new row, but ive 'lifted' the button with absolute positioning.

It seems to work well when I resize the window. I thought the layout would be more robust if I used em for the widths instead of px, which means Ive had to normalize the text sizes.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/wCvVB/9/

Notice I have had to turn off the borders from both inputs as these would add up to a number greater than 100% (ie. 80% width plus 2px (the border each side)). You could make the inputs 79% and 19% respectively and then try putting a 1px border.

I have put all inside a div with a width, but this could just as easily be the body tag which is by default 100% wide.

Comment: The only issue with your solution is that I need to give the button a big enough % width so that its always wide enough for it's text, even on the smallest device viewing my site. If I do this it means on wider device the button looks weirdly big. Is there no way of making the button just take up the space it needs (default behaviour I think), and make the search box use whatever else is left? Thanks

Comment: In which case you are limited to the solution offered by Andres Ilich. It's similar but rather than have the button expand to accommodate  the width an outer container does and the button inside stays the same. The issue of course is that visually it would not look like the box is stretching the entire width, so some white space is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contain the input fields properly and the width needs to be relative to their container. Try something like this:

**CSS**

```
.searchbar {
    width:100%;
}

.searchfield, .searchbtn {
    float:left;
}

.searchfield {
    width:70%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.searchfield input {
    width:100%;
}

.searchbtn {
    width:25%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="searchbar">
    <div class="searchfield">
        <input type="text" name="Search" value="Search" />
    </div>
    <div class="searchbtn">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/pHwYG/